# textBox change event after using backspace in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textBox that the user should fill it. Default text of the textBox is blank. I want that if the user enter some text in it, buttons will be enable.

```
    private void txtLicense_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtEconomic.Text != "")
            btnInsert.Enabled = true;
    }
```

but in this code, if the user enter some text and then erase it, it dosent work. I mean the buttons will be enable ...

how can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do `btnInsert.Enabled = false;`

```
private void txtLicense_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtEconomic.Text != "")
                btnInsert.Enabled = true;
             else
              btnInsert.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtLicense_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtEconomic.Text.Length > 0)
        btnInsert.Enabled = true;
    else
        btnInsert.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: @Tinwor It was meant to be `txtEconomic.Text.Length`, simply informing me of the error would have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You don't have any logic to disable the Button.

**Solution :** You need to add else block to disable the Button.

**Suggestion:** i would suggest you to use String Method `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check wether your textbox input string is Null or Empty.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEconomic.Text))
     btnInsert.Enabled = true;
else 
     btnInsert.Enabled = false;
```